# Change Title of Date Picker on android sdk 27

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I am implementing the android [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) in my android application.

Previously, I have been able to call the `DatePickerDialog.setTitle()` method to change the title of the Dialog.

However, while creating a project using Android SDK 27, the `DatePickerDialog.setTitle()` call doesn't seem to do anything and neither does the `DatePickerDialog.setCustomTextView()` call.

Here is my code for the calls:

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()

        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(activity, this@DatePickerFragment, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        datePickerDialog.setTitle("I was born on...")
        return datePickerDialog
    }

    override fun onDateSet(p0: DatePicker?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        TODO("Do something...")
    }
}
```

And also my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aceinteract.sleak"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.5.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.appsee:appsee-android:2.3.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Same problem here.  Looks like a bug.